# iOS 5 Storyboard navigation controller - How can I customize back button action (saving state before going back)

Tags: objective-c

I have a navigation controller I created in a storyboard. The forward and back functions work fine...The part I am struggling with is how I can save state of the application when the back button is pressed. Is there a way I can have my current view controller be notified when the back button is pressed?

How can I use viewWillDisappear in this case:

```
    ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
    readerViewController.title = model.title;
    readerViewController.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
    [readerViewController release];
```

(I am using a pdf reader library)

Comment: It's not clear why you want this. Do you want to prevent the view from begging popped off the navigation stack in some instances? Or do you just want to know after the fact?

Comment: I want to save the pdf bookmarks before going back

Comment: You can set the navigation controller delegate to whichever view is topmost on the stack (as long as that class adopts the protocol), to get notified that it will get popped.

Comment: That class (ReaderViewController) is a library class that I don't want to modify. Should I subclass it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the view controller that is on the top of the stack (presently on screen) will get the `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` messages.

`viewWillDisappear:` is a good place to save anything the user may have been editing or manipulating on that screen.

**Edit** to address your followup:

So when the user taps "back", you'll get these messages (I'm going to call the presenting view controller 'rootViewController')

1. readerViewController will get viewWillDisappear:
2. rootViewController will get viewWillAppear:
3. readerViewController will get viewDidDisappear:
4. rootViewController will get viewDidAppear:

So if you have access to the ReaderViewController source, you can add/edit methods for those events. You can also set a delegate on the navigation controller, and that delegate will get `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` and `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` as the user comes back.

But if you tell us more about this "ReaderViewController", maybe it has delegate methods you can implement to save whatever state it manipulates. What "pdf reader library" is this? And what state exactly are you trying to save?

Comment: The pdf library if vfr/Reader (search vfr/reader Git Hub) and you will find it.  I couldn't determine if there are any delegate methods.

Comment: There is one delegate method that I am using:

- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController

But I need to save the document (which is private) when clicking "Back" in my navigation controller. Even if I extend the class I don't have access to the document.

Comment: I figured it out, You aren't suppose to use a navigation controller with it.